# spark-scala: groupBy throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (null)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, indexoutofboundsexception

I started with following a RDD that has string

```
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(7665710590658745,-414963169),0,f1,1420276980302)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(8016905020647641,183812619),1,f4,1420347885727)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(6633110906332136,294201185),1,f2,1420398323110)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(6633110906332136,294201185),0,f1,1420451687525)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(7722056727387069,1396896294),0,f1,1420537469065)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(7722056727387069,1396896294),1,f1,1420623297340)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(8045651092287275,-4814845),0,f1,1420720722185)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(5170029699836178,-1332814297),0,f2,1420750531018)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(7722056727387069,1396896294),0,f1,1420807545137)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(4784119468604853,1287554938),0,f1,1421050087824)
```

Just to give an high level view on description of the data. You can think first element in the main tuple (first tuple) as a user identification, second tuple as a product identification, and third element is user's preference on the product. (for future reference I am going to mark above data set as `val userData`)

Here is how I construct `userData`:

```
val userData = data.map(x => {
  val userId = x._1.replace("_","")
  val programId = x._2
  val feature = someMethod(x._5, x._4)
  val userHashTuple = (userId, userId.hashCode)
  val programHashTuple = (programId, programId.hashCode)
  (userHashTuple, programHashTuple, x._3, timeFeature, x._4)
})
```

My goal is that if user has casted both positive `(1)` and negative `(0)` preference for a product only take the record with positive. For example:

```
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(7722056727387069,1396896294),0,f1,1420537469065)
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(7722056727387069,1396896294),1,f1,1420623297340)
```

I only want to keep

```
((26468EDE20E38,239394055),(7722056727387069,1396896294),1,f1,1420623297340)
```

Based on previously provided answer I followed following:

```
val grpData = userData.groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2)).mapValues(_.maxBy(_._3)).values
```

But I am getting an error at the stage of `groupBy`. `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (null) [duplicate 1]`
and its keep repeating the same error while increasing the duplicate number. Also exception doesn't point to my code so I am having tough time figuring out what exactly going on.

At the end I get following:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Does this mean that key is empty? but if key is empty it would still carry out the groupBy for a `""`. So I am bit confuse.

After digging around I found following: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6772

But I don't think the issue is same but thats all I got.

Comment: Can you provide more code? How is `userData` constructed from the input?

Comment: @DeanWampler added extra code. Construction of `userData` doesn't give any trouble. I did `userData.take(10).foreach(println)` looks good.

Comment: With data you've provided it is not possible to reproduce the problem. What is the type of `userData`?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem. But you could try to use reduceByKey **rdd.map(x => ((x._1,x._2),x._3)).reduceByKey((x,y) => {if(x>y) x else y })**

Comment: @zero323 userData is type of `RDD[((String, Int), (String, Int), Int, String, String)]`

Comment: Still nothing. Please try to reduce example data to the minimum required to reproduce the problem. You can start with `sc.parallelize(userData.take(10))` + rest of the pipeline and if it doesn't work just use samples (`userData.takeSample`).

Comment: @Knight71 I like your solution and I tried to do your method but I don't have access to `reduceByKey` after `rdd.map(x => ((x._1,x._2),x._3))`

Comment: @Knight71 actually I want to all 5 elements in my final results so I did `map(x => ((x._1,x._2),x._3, x._4, x._5)).reduceByKey((x,y) => {if(x>y) x else y })` which is incorrect because x._4 and x._5 are string.